# Why is the output of torch.lstsq drastically different than np.linalg.lstsq?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, torch

Pytorch provides a `lstsq` function, but the result it returns drastically differs from the numpy's version. Here is an example input and both of their results:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch 

a = torch.tensor([[1., 1, 1],
                  [2, 3, 4],
                  [3, 5, 2],
                  [4, 2, 5],
                  [5, 4, 3]])

b = torch.tensor([[-10., -3],
                  [ 12, 14],
                  [ 14, 12],
                  [ 16, 16],
                  [ 18, 16]])

a1 = a.clone().numpy()
b1 = b.clone().numpy()

x, r = torch.lstsq(b, a)

x1, res, r1, s = np.linalg.lstsq(b1, a1)

print(f'torch_x: {x}')
print(f'torch_r: {r}\n')

print(f'np_x: {x1}')
print(f'np_res: {res}')
print(f'np_r1(rank): {r1}')
print(f'np_s: {s}')
```

Output:

```
torch_x: tensor([[ 2.0000,  1.0000],
        [ 1.0000,  1.0000],
        [ 1.0000,  2.0000],
        [10.9635,  4.8501],
        [ 8.9332,  5.2418]])
torch_r: tensor([[-7.4162, -6.7420, -6.7420],
        [ 0.2376, -3.0896,  0.1471],
        [ 0.3565,  0.5272,  3.0861],
        [ 0.4753, -0.3952, -0.4312],
        [ 0.5941, -0.1411,  0.2681]])

np_x: [[-0.11452514 -0.10474861 -0.28631285]
 [ 0.35913807  0.33719075  0.54070234]]
np_res: [ 5.4269753 10.197526   1.4185953]
np_r1(rank): 2
np_s: [43.057705  5.199417]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`torch.lstq(a, b)` solves **minX L2∥bX−a∥**
while  `np.linalg.lstsq(a, b)` solves **minX L2∥aX−b∥**

So change the order of parameters passed.

Here's a sample:

import numpy as np
import torch

```
a = torch.tensor([[1., 1, 1],
                  [2, 3, 4],
                  [3, 5, 2],
                  [4, 2, 5],
                  [5, 4, 3]])

b = torch.tensor([[-10., -3],
                  [ 12, 14],
                  [ 14, 12],
                  [ 16, 16],
                  [ 18, 16]])

a1 = a.clone().numpy()
b1 = b.clone().numpy()

x, _ = torch.lstsq(a, b)

x1, res, r1, s = np.linalg.lstsq(b1, a1)

print(f'torch_x: {x[:b.shape[1]]}')

print(f'np_x: {x1}')
```

Results:

```
torch_x: tensor([[-0.1145, -0.1047, -0.2863],
        [ 0.3591,  0.3372,  0.5407]])
np_x: [[-0.11452514 -0.10474861 -0.28631285]
 [ 0.35913807  0.33719075  0.54070234]]
```

link to torch [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.lstsq.html)
link to numpy [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html)

And also the returned `rank` from numpy.lianalg.lstsq is **rank of 1st parameters** . To get rank in pytorch use `torch.matrix_rank()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it! but do you know how I can also extract the rank in pytorch as well? numpy returns a specific value for rank, but I dont know how this is done in pytorch!

Comment: @Rika use `torch.matrix_rank(required_matrix)` . Here numpy lstq returns rank of first tensor passed i.e 2nd tensor for torch lstq so use torch.matrix_rank(2nd)

Comment: Thanks a lot really appreciate it. so to be sure, you mean, I need to run the matrix_rank on the second output of ```x,y=torch.lstsq(a, b)``` i.e. y here? right? should I also call it with ```symmetric=true`` or false?

Comment: use matrix_rank(b)

Comment: It is still unclear why torch would be returning a 5-by-2 matrix.  solving bx = a where:
b is 5-by-2, a is 5-by-3, should return x which is a 2-by-3 (or 3-by-2 because torch returns the transpose)
where is a 5-by-2 matrix result coming from?!

Comment: in pytorch 1.7.1 your code above returns:
tensor([[-0.1145, -0.1047, -0.2863],
        [ 0.3591,  0.3372,  0.5407],
        [ 0.7767,  2.7653, -0.5354],
        [ 0.9024, -1.2889,  0.9052],
        [ 2.0023,  0.9431, -0.5590]])
a 5 by 3 matrix. what version of torch were you using??

Comment: @Megan Hardy check the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.lstsq.html) 
which says: 
Returned tensor `X` has shape `(max(m, n) x k)`. The first **n rows of X** contains the **solution**. If `m>n`, the residual sum of squares for the solution in each column is given by the sum of squares of elements in the remaining `m−n` rows of that column.

Comment: Here `mxn = 5x2`, `mxk = 5x3` hence outpur **x** is of shape `(max(m, n) x k) = max(5, 2) x 3 = 5x3`. And first `n rows = 2 rows` contains the souluion -> `x[:n] = x[:b.shape[1]] = x[:2]` of shape `2x3` is the solution.